# ESLint autofix is not working with coc.nvim

Tags: vim, neovim, coc.nvim

When running `eslint --fix` locally the files get formatted with no problem. However when saving a file within neovim with `autocmd BufWritePre *.js,*ts,*tsx :CocCommand eslint.executeAutofix` or by running `:CocCommand eslint.executeAutofix` inside vim, the files do not change. Please any help is appreciated, or if anyone could help me how to debug this issue would be great.

**Installed extensions**

```
coc-eslint
coc-json
coc-prettier
coc-tsserver
```

**CocInfo**

```
## versions

vim version: NVIM v0.7.2
node version: v16.17.1
coc.nvim version: 0.0.82-dbd0976c 2022-09-14 18:27:21 +0800
coc.nvim directory: /home/jiseung/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim
term: tmux
platform: linux

## Log of coc.nvim

2022-10-11T15:50:41.073 INFO (pid:47125) [plugin] - coc.nvim initialized with node: v16.17.1 after 134ms
2022-10-11T15:50:42.770 INFO (pid:47125) [attach] - receive notification: showInfo []
2022-10-11T15:50:57.116 INFO (pid:47125) [services] - registered service "eslint"
2022-10-11T15:50:57.116 INFO (pid:47125) [services] - LanguageClient ESLint state change: stopped => starting
2022-10-11T15:50:57.142 INFO (pid:47125) [services] - registered service "tsserver"
2022-10-11T15:50:57.159 INFO (pid:47125) [services] - service tsserver started
2022-10-11T15:50:57.213 INFO (pid:47125) [services] - LanguageClient ESLint state change: starting => running
2022-10-11T15:50:57.216 INFO (pid:47125) [services] - service eslint started
2022-10-11T15:50:58.653 INFO (pid:47125) [attach] - receive notification: runCommand [ 'eslint.executeAutofix' ]
2022-10-11T15:50:58.657 INFO (pid:47125) [attach] - Request action: doAutocmd [ 1, 8 ]
2022-10-11T15:51:05.810 INFO (pid:47125) [attach] - receive notification: showInfo []
```

**Plugins**

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'nvim-lua/popup.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope-fzy-native.nvim'
Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'}
Plug 'nvim-treesitter/playground'
Plug 'ThePrimeagen/harpoon'

call plug#end()
```

**coc.vim**

```
" Give more space for displaying messages.
set cmdheight=2

" Having longer updatetime (default is 4000 ms = 4 s) leads to noticeable
" delays and poor user experience.
set updatetime=300

" Don't pass messages to |ins-completion-menu|.
set shortmess+=c

" Navigate completion
inoremap <expr> <C-j> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) : "\<C-j>"
inoremap <expr> <C-k> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(1) : "\<C-k>"

" Make <CR> auto-select the first completion item and notify coc.nvim to
" format on enter, <cr> could be remapped by other vim plugin
inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"

" Use `[g` and `]g` to navigate diagnostics
" Use `:CocDiagnostics` to get all diagnostics of current buffer in location list.
nmap <silent> <C-k> <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap <silent> <C-j> <Plug>(coc-diagnostic-next)

" GoTo code navigation.
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-implementation)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)

" Use K to show documentation in preview window.
nnoremap <silent> K :call <SID>show_documentation()<CR>

function! s:show_documentation()
  if (index(['vim','help'], &filetype) >= 0)
    execute 'h '.expand('<cword>')
  elseif (coc#rpc#ready())
    call CocActionAsync('doHover')
  else
    execute '!' . &keywordprg . " " . expand('<cword>')
  endif
endfunction

" Symbol renaming.
nmap <leader>r <Plug>(coc-rename)

" Formatting selected code.
xmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)<CR>
nmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)<CR>

" Add `:Format` command to format current buffer with language server
command! -nargs=0 Format :call CocAction('format')

" Add `:Prettier` command to format current buffer with prettier
command! -nargs=0 Prettier :CocCommand prettier.formatFile

" Add `:eslint` command to format current buffer with eslint
command! -nargs=0 Eslint :CocCommand eslint.executeAutofix

" Auto format on save
autocmd BufWritePre *.py,*.html :Format
autocmd BufWritePre *.css,*scss :Prettier
autocmd BufWritePre *.js,*ts,*tsx :Eslint

" Use CTRL-S for selections ranges.
" Requires 'textDocument/selectionRange' support of language server.
nmap <silent> <C-s> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
xmap <silent> <C-s> <Plug>(coc-range-select)

" Show all diagnostics.
nnoremap <silent><nowait> <leader>d  :<C-u>CocList diagnostics<cr>
" Manage extensions.
nnoremap <silent><nowait> <leader>e  :<C-u>CocList extensions<cr>
```

**coc-settings.json**

```json
{
  "eslint.enable": true,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vim or Neovim. Use Coc's official support channels.